# Display the outline of many polygons

Tags: qgis, symbology, formatting

I need help formatting an outline on a layer. The problem is that i have a layer with this attribute table:
[image: Attribute Table]

And the aspect of this layer is like that:
[image: Aspect of the layer]

What I need is to show an outline not around every "Dicofre", but around the entire layer, i.e. around all "SGRU".
Basically I want this but with an outline around all layer:
[image: Aspecto of layer #2]

I hope I made myself clear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want it just in the Display, or do you want to make it one polygon in the data as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for the dissolve function

[image]

[image]

Comment: right, that actually works, however it makes me lose too much information :/

Comment: Well you are joining everything together.  What do you need to do?

Comment: Sometimes I need to see the information on detail but I can keep the original layer under the dissolved and check it when I need. Thank you very much

Comment: Well, you can keep the original layer for the information and just use the dissolved one for the visualization.

Comment: Ever tried to do this for Corine Land Cover? It takes AGES.

Comment: I agree, the dissolve tool takes forever and frequently crashes.

Comment: The dissolve function is very slow ...

Answer (score 1):

I found that there is a quite simple solution to this by using symbol levels. Basically, make a symbol for the fill and below one that will draw the outline. Then, using symbol levels, make sure the outline always lies below the fill layer. Thus, only the outer borer of the outline will be visible, sticking out under the fill. Here's a video showing the process:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVu-KVgwbbs

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to display the polygon, and not the actual boundaries between the features, simply go into the Style tab of the layer and either 1)  change the outline pattern to no line or 2) make the outline width = 0.

This will give you the polygon as shown above, but retain the feature attributes.  Note this this won't truly be the "boundary" of the feature (which I would consider to be a line), but rather the "area" of the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Use buffer then dissolve the resulting polygon if you have a lot of shapes.